# Medium.com's RSS feeds are invalid, how can I get it to work?

Tags: php, rss

A year ago medium.com [announced that it would provide RSS feeds](https://twitter.com/Medium/status/274669061680533504).

Yet it seems that none of their feeds validate, for example [this page](https://medium.com/feed/help-center) doesn't not validate at [Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org/) (neither do any other feeds from medium.com that I have tried).

I am using Wordpress and when I enter a URL for an RSS feed I receive this message on the page that's loading the script:

> RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: Empty reply from server

Any tips? Seems like it's out of my control which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: You could write a PHP script to consume them, clean them up, and rewrite them as valid XML in real time (you'd provide the URL of your script to Wordpress, which would just see the valid RSS). Out of interest, in what way are they invalid?

Comment: http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Ffeed%2Fhelp-center

line 15, column 8: Undefined channel element: author
line 16, column 53: Email address is missing real name

Maybe this is the issue?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819554/problem-with-rss-feed-and-cdata

Comment: Maybe `<author />` isn't part of the RSS standard? Try comparing this with a feed that Wordpress likes, and work out the difference? You can put a (static) copy of this feed on a web server and edit it, and find out what you need to delete/change in order to get it to work. Then, write the script I suggest above - should take an hour or two using SimpleXML.

Comment: Seems to be the best option. I'm pretty n00b when it comes to PHP though which is a shame since this is much more work for something that ideally takes 1 second to implement.

Comment: If the problem really is just the author field, the solution is about three lines of code: load XML, `unset` the author field, render the XML. But find out what is invalid first, by experimentation if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The feed is not 100% valid but I doubt this is the problem because it has an extra `<author>` element which a LOT of RSS feeds actually have in them. It also misses the name in the `webMaster` fied, which again is not a real issue based on [our](http://superfeedr.com) experience.

Now, the error you're getting seems to be more related to an HTTP error/problem. It seems to indicate that your WP was not able to connect to the medium servers. You should probably check that.
If this is a server that you own, maybe try to `curl` the feed URL from that box?

Also, what's the HTTP library you're using? Is it part of a plugin?

Comment: I'm using the RSS Wordpress Widget, that comes with Wordpress (no plugins), to load the rss feed. It looks like this: http://www.lotusseedsdesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/rss-widget.gif Other RSS feeds I can simply enter in and it works.

Comment: I believe that the script that loads the RSS feed is somewhere here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-includes and is named either: feed-rss.php, feed-rss2.php, rss-functions.php or rss.php

Comment: The server is hosted by Godaddy.com also, I do have full access to it but am not saavy enough to know what or how to curl a feed.

Answer (score 1):

[One of the Medium Engineer's describes](https://medium.com/medium-eng/it-takes-a-village-to-read-an-rss-feed-84e63a3c9094#.8xln2my9f) the WordPress empty response in a Medium posts as a response to concerns about pingback overload.  I've worked around this on a few projects by using [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com) to create a sort of 'proxy' endpoint where I can access the RSS feed.  By taking the Medium RSS URL and pasting it into Feedburner, you get a `http://feeds.feedburner.com/XYZ` URL that seems to get imported into WordPress, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Convert RSS to JSON using the below link. replace your user name instead of `@userNAME`
if you use RSS there is a CROS error that will occur.

`https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@userNAME`